# FileManager MoveItem Callback - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, file-manager

I'm using the FileManager for edit, move and delete files in my App. But how can be sure that the method moveItem is completed? Is there any possible callback? I read something about a FileManagerDelegate but I didn't find enough information how to use it.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`moveItem(at:to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1414750-moveitem) method is synchronous, which means that it won't move on to any lines of code afterwards until the operation is completed. In Swift, it also `throws`, so you know that something went wrong if it gives you an error, and everything is fine if it moves on. You should call it like this:

```
do{
    try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: origURL, to: newURL)
}
catch let error{
    // Handle any errors here
    dump(error)
}
```

In Objective-C, it returns a `BOOL` that specifies if the operation succeeded, and takes a pass-by-reference `NSError` that it will configure if something went wrong. For example:

```
NSError *error = nil;
BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtURL:origURL toURL:newURL error:&error];
if(!success || error){
    // Something went wrong, handle the error here
}
else{
    // Everything succeeded
}
```

Comment: It's synchronous but you can still dispatch the work to another queue and dispatch your completion back to the main one. Check my answer.

Comment: You could do this, but ultimately it'd be easier/clearer/more configurable imo if you just handle the queues and whatever code afterwards at the call site

Comment: The point I am trying to make is this kind of work doesn't belong to the main thread (in my option). Where you handle your queues it's up to the developer.

Answer (score 2):

You could extend your `FileManager` to add a few methods for more convenience:

```
extension FileManager {
    func moveItem(at url: URL, toUrl: URL, completion: @escaping (Bool, Error?) -> ()) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {

            do {
                try self.moveItem(at: url, to: toUrl)
            } catch {
                // Pass false and error to completion when fails
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                   completion(false, error)
                }
            }

            // Pass true to completion when succeeds
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(true, nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
FileManager.default.moveItem(at: atUrl, toUrl: toUrl) { (succeeded, error) in
    if succeeded {
        // Success
    } else {
        // Something went wrong
    }
}
```